# Unit testing a function with callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I have a function in node.js:

```
fs.readdir(filesPath, function(err, items) {

    items.forEach(function(filename){


        fs.readFile(path.join(filesPath,filename), {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err,data){

        //do some calculations with data from each file, the result is an object 'finalOutput'


    fs.stat(path.join(__dirname,'output.csv'), function (err, stat) {
        //check if file exists

            fs.appendFile(path.join(__dirname,'output.csv'), csv, function (err) {
            // append output to csv 
    });
}
        else {
            //create file

            fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname,'output.csv'), fields, function (err, stat) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log('File saved');
    });
}
});



   })
  })
});
```

I would like to write tests on the 'finalOutput' variable, the content of the files (for example, if a file is empty the output should be X, and so on), and the existence of output files. But when I run npm test (I am using mocha and chai, I get ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined at Context')

This is an example of a test I want to run:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
expect = chai.expect,
mypreviouscode = require('./mypreviouscode');

describe('test1', function() {
it('There output should always exist', function() {
expect(finalOutput.to.exist);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`expect(finalOutput).to.exist`

There isn't to.exist in the finalOutput object, this is present in the object returned by chai's `expect` function.

That being said, your test will still fail since your error is telling you that the `finalOutput` object doesn't exist(is undefined). If you want there to be a global `finalOutput` object then you must declare it inside your code. You may do it like this `global.finalOutput = finalOutput` (I guess you declared it with `let finalOuput` or `const finalOutput` or `var finalOutput`)

Comment: I have declared it as a global now but it is still undefined. It works fine when I execute the function, but not during the tests. Is it because the function is reading the files in async?

Comment: Yes, apparently. You should have a way to wait for all async stuff to finish executing before running your `expect` in your test. If I'm not mistaken mocha will wait if you return a promise `it('description', function(){ return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {setTimeout(() => expect(...), 2000)})})`